# allocating memory for structs

Tags: c, struct

If I have a struct:

```
typedef struct t_node {
    char* id;
    struct t_node* next;
}TypeNode;
```

if I have a constructor like this:

```
void conTypeNode(TypeNode* node, char* id) {
    node = malloc(sizeof(TypeNode));
    node->id = malloc(strlen(id)+1);
    strcpy(node->id, id);
    node->next = NULL;
}
```

then this code will sig-fault:

```
void printTypeNode(TypeNode node) {
    printf("%s\n", node.id);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    TypeNode* head = NULL;
    conTypeNode(head, "head");
    printTypeNode(*head); //sig-fault 11: invalid read
}
```

Could someone explain why this happens? I know that if I change the syntax of `conTypeNode` to take a double pointer then it works fine. I was thinking maybe it is because `malloc` will change the address stored in the local variable `node` but not in the variable `head`?

Comment: @Haris, my bad, I fixed it. I copied some code and meant to simplify it. The sig-fault is not related to this.

Comment: This code won't even compile, because `conTypeHead` takes two parameters, not one. Post an SSCCE

Comment: `conTypeNode` should be called with `id` parameter.

Comment: Stop updating the code in the question! Post the actual one.

Comment: @EugeneSh. there were some bugs that needed fixing.

Comment: Of course there are! Otherwise why would you ask?

Comment: @EugeneSh. bugs unrelated to the actual problem. I was simplifying some actual code and missed some stuff. Complaining about this is not constructive to my question.

Comment: By editing the problems already pointed by some people you are effectively invalidating these answers and the effort these people made. It is not respectful at very least and against SO etiquette.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void conTypeNode(TypeNode **node, char* id) {
    *node = malloc(sizeof(TypeNode));
    (*node)->id = malloc(strlen(id)+1);
    strcpy((*node)->id, id);
    (*node)->next = NULL;
}
```

...because you have to return the allocated node.

Comment: So the code you posted is the code I am actually using, with the double pointer. This was more of a sanity check question, is my explanation for why my code is wrong accurate?

Comment: Yes, your explanation is correct. Your `node` was on the stack, the result of `malloc` is placed in it and when you return, the stack is gone... hence, the caller can see no efect of what you did.

Answer (score 1):

In `C` all functions parameters are passed *by value*. Even if pointer is passed a called function only gets its value (memory address) and its copy but doesn't get an original pointer so it's not able to modify it. To do what you want you need to pass a pointer to pointer like this:

```
void conTypeNode(TypeNode** node, char* id) {
    *node = malloc(sizeof(TypeNode));
    (*node)->id = malloc(strlen(id)+1);
    strcpy((*node)->id, id);
    (*node)->next = NULL;
}

   TypeNode* head = NULL;
   conTypeNode(&head, "aaa");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please post code that will compile. Where is `node->type` declared? Where is your second argument being passed to `conTypeNode`?

Ata any rate, I can see in `main` that `head` is null. Then you dereference `head` when passing to `printTypeNode()`.

You cannot dereference NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Originaly , in what you do is , copy is created and memory is allocated to that and not to `head` . So, this is what won't work . `return` the pointer from function .

What you can do is this -

```
TypeNode *conTypeNode(char* id) {
   TypeNode *node;
   node = malloc(sizeof(TypeNode));           //allocate memory 
   node->id = malloc(strlen(id)+1);
   strcpy(node->id, id);
   node->next = NULL;
   return node;                               //return pointer
}
```

And in `main` call like this -

```
head=conTypeNode("head");
```

and don't forget to `free` memory in `main`.